# Do templates provide type checking

Tags: c++, templates, types

So I understand that templates can provide a way to do generic programming for example :

```
template <typename T>

T add(T x, T y){ return x + y}
```

Now I am wondering is there any type check templates provide? Or should I just define x and y as an integer to avoid errors.

Comment: Can't you try it with a compiler?

Comment: The template mechanism won´t check if the types are add-able, but if not, the `+` in the return will produce an error (there, and not where the template is instantiated. Can be confusing)

Comment: Please clarify your question. If you only need `x` and `y` to be `int`s, why is `add` a template function?

Answer (score 0):

If you define operator+ for the type T, then there would be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, **there will be type checking**, so you won't be able to do something like:

```
string c = add(3UL, 2.0E4);  /* ERROR: the type of the result and the types of the arguments must match */
```

Also, as has been appointed, T must be a type with add operator `+` defined on it.  As far as you obey these rules, you are free to do whatever you want with your generic function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T add(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    string c = add(3UL, 'A');
}
```

Will lead to:

```
$ make pru
g++     pru.cc   -o pru
pru.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
pru.cc:13:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘add(long unsigned int, char)’
pru.cc:13:28: note: candidate is:
pru.cc:6:3: note: template<class T> T add(T, T)
make: *** [pru] Error 1
```